# Usage of the word "issue"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm confused about the usage of the word "issue". How does it differ from "problem"?

Also, could you tell me whether this sentence correct: "There are different opinions on the issue of learning foreign languages". I feel this my guts that it's not, but I cannot be 100% sure since I'm not a native speaker.

**Can I use the phrase "the issue of ____" and "the problem of ___" just with any noun?**

> The problem of making or buying presents
>   The problem of souvenirs
>   The issue of learning foreign languages

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

'Issue' has a broader sense than 'problem' as the former means a subject or problem that people are thinking and talking about. Nevertheless, 'problem' means a thing people have to deal with or solve.

E.g. 1 - 'There are a number of issues to be discussed in the meeting. It reflects the word 'issue' refers to the topics and matters people have to discuss.

E.g. 2 'There are a number of problems for the department to address.' Then, problems means something to solve.

The issue of poverty / The problem of poverty (noun) are both correct in grammar.

Comment: Yes. The modern trend of using "issue", when the better word would be "problem" depresses me. Biggest culprits are technical support people who insist on calling your problem an "issue" - as if it isn't in fact a problem.